# IE custom input showing the default appearance

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to create a custom `input`, that can be either of type `radio` or `checkbox`. But I'm facing a problem with the css on IE browser.

**Expected Result:**

[image: Expected result]

**IE browser Result**

[image]

**Input JSX**

```
const CheckBox2: FC<ICheckBox2Props> = ({ label, type = "checkbox", className, labelClassName, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <label className={[styles.container, className ?? ""].join(" ")}>
            <input
                {...props}
                type={type}
            />
            {label && <span className={[styles.label, labelClassName ?? ""].join(" ")} >{label}</span>}
        </label>
    );
};

export default CheckBox2;
```

**Input CSS**

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 48px;

    >input {
        cursor: pointer;

        height: 17px;
        width: 17px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ABACAD;
        border-radius: 2px;

        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -ms-appearance: none;
        -o-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;

        outline: none;

        &:checked {
            height: 17px;
            width: 17px;

            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #2D3641;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: #2D3641;

            background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/icons/ico_check.png);
            background-size: 10px 9px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        }
    }

    .label{
        margin-left: 16px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution nor the best practice either, but here's something that I came with:

**MY JSX**

```
const CheckBox2: FC<ICheckBox2Props> = ({ label, type = "checkbox", className, labelClassName, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <label className={[styles.container, className ?? ""].join(" ")}>
            <input
                {...props}
                type={type}
            />
            <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
            </div>
            {label && <span className={[styles.label, labelClassName ?? ""].join(" ")} >{label}</span>}
        </label>
    );
};
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 48px;
    position: relative;

    .inputContainer{
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        cursor: pointer;

        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ABACAD;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    >input{
        opacity: 0;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;

        &:checked + .inputContainer {
            height: 16px;
            width: 16px;

            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 1px solid #2D3641;
            border-radius: 2px;
            background-color: #2D3641;

            background-image: url(../../../../assets/images/icons/ico_check.png);
            background-size: 10px 9px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        } 
    }

}

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .container{
        .inputContainer{
            top: 2px;
            left: 0px
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are using CSS **appearance** in your code.

```
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
```

CSS **appearance** is not supported in the IE browser and -ms prefix will not help to fix it. I think this is the cause of the issue.

[image]

Reference:

[CSS Appearance](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)

I did not get any alternative for CSS appearance.

You can try to use developer tools to view the applied CSS properties. It can help to understand the issue.